# How can I convert List-alike stiring to an actual list?

Tags: python, string, list

How do I convert string that looks like this:

```
['Point Target', 'Channeled']
```

To an actual List of elements (in this example, *Point Target* and *Channeled*)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/3692099

Comment: If you have the choice, produce a standard interchange format like JSON instead of dumping raw Python literals.

Comment: I'd suggest you investigate how you end up with a string that looks like a list first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use eval("['Point Target', 'Channeled']").

But be careful if you get the list from an untrusted source as eval will evaluate everything that it gets. So don't use it e.g on unfiltered input from a webinterface.

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval`.